# I am trying to connect to a remote server using the ssh

Tags: ssh

But I am getting the following error:

> ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

I executing the following command:

```
sudo ssh root@example.net
```

Can this be due to somekind of firewall settings or because the server is overlaoded?

Comment: You don't need to sudo to ssh to another box as root, just ssh root@where-ever from your current id.  You only need sudo if you're using key exchange as the root user.  Also, never ssh into a box as root.  Having said all that - try ssh -v -v -v root@whatever and see if you get any meaningful output (-v makes it more verbose).

Comment: Have you specifically enabled root logins over SSH? I know they're disabled in Ubuntu, and you really shouldn't be logging in as root via SSH anyways.

Answer (score 4):

It's likely a firewall issue, I can connect fine from here (it asks me for a password).

Please do not use `sudo ssh`, just `ssh` is fine. Also, disable passwordbased authentication and use keybased auth if possible.

To diagnose problems, run ssh with the `-v` option (`-vvv` for maximum verbosity):

```
ssh -vvv user@host
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the message you'll see when there are two machines using the same IP address.

Comment: confirmed, I had a `byobu` session that I detached from, tried ssh'ing back into the server and got blocked. setup a proxy to get a different IP address, ran ssh again and voila. Thanks @John Schmitt

Answer (score 1):

- try ssh -vvv
- (re)moving your .ssh/config to let's say /tmp and try ssh again
- try regenerating your keys (client then server)
- try to ssh from same box to same box just for test
- temporary disable your firewall